# PHP Function rename fails “No such file or directory"…

Tags: php, rename

Rename Functions fails. i already tried a lot of different solutions of this forum but nothing helps.
This is my Code:

```php
$dirname='rechnungen/';
$handleu=opendir($dirname);

while ( $ufile = readdir ( $handleu ) ) {
    
    $ufile  = substr($ufile,11);

    foreach ($mydata as $nr => $uinhalt)
    {
        
        $ufilename = $uinhalt['File'].'.pdf';
       
        if($ufilename == $ufile) {
            rename($dirname.$ufile, $dirname.'ER'.$uinhalt['Zahl'].'_'.$ufile ); 
        }
    }
}
closedir( $handleu );
```

I get this warnings:

```text
Warning: rename(rechnungen/REGW-2020-143.pdf,rechnungen/ER013_REGW-2020-143.pdf): No such file or directory in /volume1/web/sevdesk/rechnungen.php on line 162 
Warning: rename(rechnungen/REGW-2021-011.pdf,rechnungen/ER011_REGW-2021-011.pdf): No such file or directory in /volume1/web/sevdesk/rechnungen.php on line 162 
Warning: rename(rechnungen/REGW-2021-014.pdf,rechnungen/ER015_REGW-2021-014.pdf): No such file or directory in /volume1/web/sevdesk/rechnungen.php on line 162 
Warning: rename(rechnungen/REGW-2021-009.pdf,rechnungen/ER012_REGW-2021-009.pdf): No such file or directory in /volume1/web/sevdesk/rechnungen.php on line 162 
Warning: rename(rechnungen/REGW-2021-007.pdf,rechnungen/ER014_REGW-2021-007.pdf): No such file or directory in /volume1/web/sevdesk/rechnungen.php on line 162
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Where's `$mydata` coming from? What does it contain?

Comment: $mydata gets elements from a json file:

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < count($elements['objects']);$i++) {

        $mydata[$k] = array('File' => $newfile,
                            'Datum' => $showdate,
                            'Zahl' => "");   
}

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: - i tried different paths

Comment: What have you tried to **debug** the problem? Like, checking for the file existance before renaming, or checking for permissions?

Comment: - i used mkdir to build the folder
- i tried microtime to delay the loop 
- i changed the permissions to 777

Comment: And what have you tried to **debug** the problem? Have you tried to check whether the files exist before moving them? Calling `substr` on the filename might remove parts of the original filename

Comment: Yes the files are there. I can use the same loop without the rename function. That runs perfect and i get all the files with the real name from the folder. Only the rename function do not work.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the paths in .`./rechnungen/file.pdf`,

may you have to use the full path and you have to give the files and directories **full permissions**.

```
$path = "/volume1/web/sevdesk/";
$dirname= $path.'rechnungen/';
```

Comment: I'm afraid not!